# How do solar panels lose efficiency and die over time?

Tags: energy, solar-cells

Why do solar panels have a limited amount of lifespan? What goes wrong in them by the time passes? What changes happen in them that causes it to lose efficiency? What are the factors?
It seems to me that they should last as long as there is a Sun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things cause them to "wear out".

First, exposing solar cells to heat will very slowly cause the doping materials in the silicon to diffuse away from their junctions, impairing their effectiveness. If they never got hot, this wouldn't happen, and if they get too hot, they can be completely destroyed within seconds.

Second, solar cells have to be protected from their environment (water & dirt) which is usually done by covering them with sheets of glass. With time, the glass surface gets grimed up and scratched & pitted by windblown sand and grit, which reduces the glass's ability to transmit light. This is a particular problem in dry & dusty regions where there's lots of sun and cheap real estate.